# React Redux Loading bar for react router navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

So I'd like to implement a loading bar just like github has. It should start loading on a click to another page and finish when it arrived.

I'm using material-ui and for the loader react-progress-bar-plus.

I tried to use react-router's lifecycle hooks, namely componentDidUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps to set the state to be finished.

For start, I attached an onTouchTap function to the menu items but it just does not want to work properly.

What is the best way to implement this feature?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [router-resolver](https://github.com/minhtranite/router-resolver) with [react-progress-bar-plus](https://github.com/minhtranite/react-progress-bar-plus).
See this example: 
http://minhtranite.github.io/router-resolver/ex-4

**The usage example:**

```
// app.js
//...
import {RouterResolver} from 'router-resolver';
//...
const routes = {
  path: '/',
  component: App,
  indexRoute: {
    component: require('components/pages/PageHome')
  },
  childRoutes: [
    require('./routes/Example1Route'),
    require('./routes/Example2Route'),
    require('./routes/Example3Route')
  ]
};

const renderInitial = () => {
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
};

const onError = (error) => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router routes={routes}
    history={history}
    render={props => (
      <RouterResolver {...props} renderInitial={renderInitial} onError={onError}/>
    )}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And:

```
// components/pages/PageExample1.js
import React from 'react';
import Document from 'components/common/Document';

class PageExample1 extends React.Component {
  static resolve() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('simple data');
      }, 2000);
    });
  };

  static propTypes = {
    response: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Document title='Example1 | Router resolver' className='page-ex-1'>
        <h1>Example 1: {this.props.response}</h1>
      </Document>
    );
  }
}

export default PageExample1;
```

Comment: @Grego Would you please accept this? It'd be my first accepted answer :) Thanks friend

Comment: Hi, I see this https://github.com/mironov/react-redux-loading-bar with much more stars, is this still up to date after two years ?

Comment: Thanks @DimitriKopriwa for mentioning it! You can post it as an answer because it's more fair that way, instead of me updating the answer I think :) But otherwise lemme know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's ok you can had it to your answers, that doesn't hurt

Answer (score 1):

I made a small package [react-router-loading](https://github.com/victortrusov/react-router-loading) that allows you to show loading indicator and fetch some data before switching the screen.

Just use `Switch` and `Route` from this package instead of `react-router-dom`:

```js
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-loading";
```

Add `loading` props to the Route where you want to wait something:

```js
<Route path="/my-component" component={MyComponent} loading/>
```

And then somewhere at the end of fetch logic in `MyComponent` add `loadingContext.done();`:

```js
import { LoadingContext } from "react-router-loading";
const loadingContext = useContext(LoadingContext);

const loading = async () => {
    //fetching some data

    //call method to indicate that fetching is done and we are ready to switch
    loadingContext.done();
};
```